# Stream distinct() with repeated objects

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.6.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR with a restful architecture
I have this object:

```
public class Menu  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

     @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Menu menu = (Menu) o;

        return id == menu.id;
    }
...
}
```

I also have this piece of code in the controller:

```
List<Menu> favoriteMenus = new ArrayList<Menu>();

        favoriteMenus.addAll(user.getFavoriteMenus());
        favoriteMenus.addAll(applicationProfileService
                .menusByProfile(user.getApplicationSetup().getApplicationProfile().getProfileKey()));

        favoriteMenus = 
                favoriteMenus
                    .stream()
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but despite of `distinct()` there are repeated menus in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing the reference equality of `id` instead of its value equality (more on that e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)), and `id` is a [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html):

> The `Long` class wraps a value of the primitive type `long` in an object.

Change `id == menu.id` to `id.equals(menu.id)`, and it should work (provided there are no other bugs here).

Comment: …or change the field’s type to `long`.